# c# server won't recognize android

Tags: c#, java

This is my server in C# 
127.0.0.1 with port 4444

```
    using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


public class serv
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            // use local m/c IP address, and 

            // use the same in the client


            /* Initializes the Listener */
            TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 4444);

            /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
            myList.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 4444...");
            Console.WriteLine("The local End point is: " +
                              myList.LocalEndpoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");
        m:
            Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

            byte[] b = new byte[100];
            int k = s.Receive(b);

            char cc = ' ';
            string test = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");
            for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
                cc = Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
                test += cc.ToString();
            }

            switch (test)
            {
                case "1":
                    break;


            }

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
            s.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");


            /* clean up */
            goto m;
            myList.Stop();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

}
```

This is my android (client) code in JAVA

```
package com.example.aclient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     private Socket client;
     private PrintWriter printwriter;
     private EditText textField;
     private Button button;
     private String messsage;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); //reference to the text field
      button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);   //reference to the send button

      //Button press event listener
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {

        messsage = textField.getText().toString(); //get the text message on the text field
        textField.setText("");      //Reset the text field to blank

        try {

         client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444);  //connect to server
         printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
         printwriter.write(messsage);  //write the message to output stream

         printwriter.flush();
         printwriter.close();
         client.close();   //closing the connection

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
      });

     }
    }
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <EditText
         android:inputType="text"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Whay server on C# don't recognize android client??
I don't know how connect C# server with android client??
This is my first server and I don't know
much about servers..so please help me!

Comment: Define "recognize" in this context.  What indication do you have that there is a problem?

Comment: Please tell us until which line gets executed in the server code. Do you see in the server's console any `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: yes, i see that http://i40.tinypic.com/a5hhn5.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is `localhost`, your own machine. If you host a server in C# on your local PC and you have a Java application that looks a lot like Android that is surely running on another machine (your cellphone, tablet or enmulated cellphone or tablet) that is not the same machine. You need to communicate by using an IP address that both machines know and both machines trace back to the same physical box.

On your PC, `127.0.0.1` is your PC.
On your tablet, `127.0.0.1` is your tablet, not your PC.

Look up the IP of your PC in your network (Enter ipconfig in the Console if you are running Windows) and use that. Make sure you use a public IP when you deploy.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use 10.0.2.2, as you'll be using your emulator, localhost refers to the emulated device not the machine

Comment: which address i must use for server eich for client??
IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); ??
client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444);  //connect to server ??